# Several highlights in google maps embed API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I would like to add several highlight places using the Embed API of Google Maps in an Iframe like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBstlDO5AXkMg6xOjrkTJliYabsODR2vYA&q=Harvard+University,Parque+explora" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I add several locations to the q parameter?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use [mymap](https://www.google.com/maps/d/), or the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=ja) to do it. Embed API does not support multiple markers.

For using My Map, you need to set your maps to public before you can embed it onto your site.
[image]

To generate the embed url, it is under the 3`...` next to the share button

If you decided to do it with the API, you might want to reference to the [Markers part of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=ja).